# Dynamically checkbox selection on Grid Load

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using selection model. Where I am selecting some record and sending to backend. On reload of grid I want those record to be selected. So I am copy those record to the array with index. Now When I am reloading I want to select it again. Bui I am getting this error.

**Uncaught TypeError: item.getId is not a function**

Here What I am trying

```
store.on('load', function(thistore, records , successful , operation , eOpts){
        me.store.loadData(thistore.data.items);
        var checkRec = me.checkRec;
        var sm = me.getSelectionModel();
        for(var i=0; i<checkRec.length; i++){
            sm.select(checkRec[i].index,true);
        }
});
```

Can any one suggest me how to improve the code.

Comment: Can you please try to be more specific?

Comment: @thakurinbox Yes It is as simple as selecting a record while grid loaded. I have `record` and `index` of row. (As you can see in code).

Comment: Why do not you bind?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand, What and how I need to bind

Comment: {
 xtype: 'checkbox',
 bind: '{model.nameYouProperty}'
}

Comment: Or { xtype: 'checkbox', bind: '{record.nameYouProperty}' }

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['name', 'age'],
            listeners: {
                load: function (store, records, successful, operation, eOpts) {
                    for(var i=0;i<store.getCount();i++) {
                        store.getAt(i).set('checked', true);
                    }
                }
            },
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json'
                }
            },
            autoLoad: true
        })

        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'POC',
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'grid',
                id: 'gridid',
                store: store,
                selModel: {
                    selType: 'rowmodel',
                    mode: 'SIMPLE'
                },
                columns: [{
                    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'checked'
                }, {
                    text: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    text: 'Age',
                    dataIndex: 'age',
                    flex: 1
                }]
            }]
        })
    }
});
```

**Working fiddle:** https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29ui